# flyway run repair before every migration

Tags: flyway

I am testing flywaydb in our dev env. Testing the command line 4.2.0 for MySQL DB. Trying to automate the process using chef. I have a question regarding repair. If I have a syntax error in the .sql file, it errors out. After I fix the .sql file, I need to run “repair” before I can run “migrate” again.  Can I run the command “repair” even though there were no errors during the run. By default the cookbook would run “repair” and then “migrate”. Do you see any issues?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will work as expected for your dev environment. Repair can be run repeatedly.

For production I would not recommend this approach as you will lose the audit trail of whether any migrations have been modified as another task that repair does is recalculate the checksums of the migrations (source: [Flyway docs](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/commandline/repair)).